# Dividing divs into columns

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

How to divide child divs into 5 columns where the data is populated dynamically using ng-repeat.
Is there a way doing it with css

Comment: What have you tried? Have a go yourself first and then come back when you have a specific problem

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create 5 divs inside the parent div as shown below and apply css as shown. Note that width of .column is 100%/5 = 20% for 5 columns.

HTML / CSS

```css
.row{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.column{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "column">
    </div>
  
    <div class = "column">
    </div>
  
    <div class = "column">    
    </div>
  
    <div class = "column">
    </div>
  
    <div class = "column">
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Data is populated dynamically there might be 6 columns or even more or in some scenarios there might be less than 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since the outer column can accept up to 10 columns and the inner column is 2 column wide, then the 6th inner column will stack to the next row since the inner column can't fit with the outer column anymore.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-md-2">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```